# XMLHttpRequest POST response different than API Test response (Postman,Apitester.com etc)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, http

I have application that is sending pin to get auth token. I'm using https://apitester.com/# and js xmlhttprequest. It's Node JS on Windows 10. Something goes wrong when I send request from JS app
Howewer I get good response on ApiTester. I have tried it also on Postman and it returns me also a good result. Headers are important to this application work

```js
function REQ_POST(url, body, headers) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "POST", url, false );
    xmlHttp.headers = headers
    xmlHttp.send( body );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

I have function that sends POST request to url
Body and Headers are stringlified json
When i run this i get

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

But when i run it in api tester (https://apitester.com/)
The same url the same headers the same body
I get good response

```
{"IsError":false,"Token":"aaaaaaaaaaa"}
```

Additional Info

```
HEADERS:
{"RequestMobileType":"RegisterDevice","User-Agent":"MobileUserAgent","Content-Type":"application/json"}
```

```
BODY:
{"PIN":"31231"}
```

EDIT 1

```js
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "POST", url, false );
    headers.forEach(element => {
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader(element[0],element[1])
    });
    xmlHttp.send( body );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
```

I Changed headers var to array of arrays and it still doesn't work
There is no xmlHttp.headers so i used xmlHttp.setRequestHeader
and it still doesn't work

https://apitester.com/#

[apitester com (Headers screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYvcr.png)

Comment: I think you should use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). It’s easier to set up headers and it’s a bit more modern than XMLHttpRequest. It’s supported by all major browsers and there are plenty of polyfills for IE. I’m not posting this as an answer because it’s not, but take it as a workaround.